# Colors of links not working, 3 examples

Tags: html, css

I have these 3 links and they are not working properly. Usually **one** of the
css files are applied, the rest isn't.

For example the first 2 links **are working** with the hover, the third one **isn't.** 
The first 2 aren't green when you don't hover over them, the third one **is** green.

Best thing is to try it out to see it.

Edit: make the links green, and when you hover over them make them black. Right now it is the one or the other. This is what I want

Anyone knows what the problem may be ?

```
<style>
  .links {
    padding-top: 2%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  a:link{
    color: green;
  }

  a:hover {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
</style>

<div class="links">
  <a href="https://www.google.com/" font color="green">Link</a>
  </div>

  <div class="links">
  <a href="https://www.google.com/">Link</a>
  </div>

  <div class="links">
  <a href="https://www.google.com/"><font color="green">Link</font></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: what do you need to do? make links go green on hover?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you're looking for. But first, check you HTML, all those anchor tags aren't similar

Comment: make the links green, and when you hover over them make them white. Right now it is the one or the other

Comment: It is because you need to give style="color:green;" for the anchor.

Comment: Yep, with links (or 'anchor' tag), work on them, not on the `div.links` wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove the inline  tags and their styles and just use CSS like so:

CSS

```
.links {
    padding-top: 2%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  a {
    color: green;
  }

  a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="links">
  <a href="https://www.google.com/">Link</a>
  </div>

  <div class="links">
  <a href="https://www.google.com/">Link</a>
  </div>

  <div class="links">
  <a href="https://www.google.com/">Link</a>
  </div>
```

You've got some tag <> out of place too.

Answer (score 0):

The colour of the `<a>` will only affect the colour of the `<font>` inside it if the `<font>` has `color: inherit` (which it does not).

If you want want to change the colour of the font element, then you must select it in the CSS:

```
a:hover font {
    color: black;
}
```

You should avoid the `<font>` element (it was deprecated when HTML 4 was published two decades ago and marked as obsolete in HTML 5) in favour of semantic markup and CSS (in this case that would mean applying CSS directly to the `<a>` and removing the `<font>` entirely).

---

`a:link` matches only anchors which are unvisited links. You need to also select `a:visited` to match the visited links too:

```
a:link,
a:visited { color: green; }
```

Or you could use `a { color: green }` to match all `<a>` elements, even if they don't have an `href` attribute.

Comment: Hmm it is not working for me, the color green is not showing up

Comment: @Lego — Drat. I didn't notice you were asking about two different things there. I only answered one of your questions. Try to avoid asking multiple questions at once.

Comment: @Lego — Updated with an answer to your other question.

Answer (score -1):

you are using the style wrong , this is the correct way to do it :

```
 <div class="links">
  <a href="https://www.google.com/" style="color:green">Link</a>
  </div>

  <div class="links">
  <a href="https://www.google.com/">Link</a>
  </div>

  <div class="links">
  <a href="https://www.google.com/" style="color:green">Link</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid (end tag `</font>` without opening tag, and the style attribute is more specific than the selector in the stylesheet, so it won't solve the problem.

Comment: The hover will not work. The style attribute will override it.